# Getting the name in name textbox of a MSI Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have a question:
I created a project and created a MSI to install my software. When i install it, when it asks me for the key, on the top there's a textbox which asks for you name. I need to take that name and put it in a .txt file. Is there any way to do it? I've read that i could maybe use a DLL, but to be honest, i'm still too noob in c++, and i'm REALLY running out of time. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/00db2a78-c161-4986-9d86-c1b6d2e3c3a1/how-can-i-get-the-windows-user-name-in-msi?forum=winformssetup

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know much about custom actions in setup projects there is no quick answer. Basically, if you can write the code to write that name into the text file you're half way there. Then you need a custom action in which you pass the USERNAME property in the CustomActionData field of the custom action (hit f4 to see the properties window of a custom action). This might help:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/

and use [USERNAME] in the CustomActionData because USERNAME is the name of the property in that dialog and the square brackets cause it to be resolved to the actual entered string.